# IDA 7.0 (free) fails to load symbols with message "DWARF: Cannot determine location of DWARF info" during debugging

Tags: ida, symbols, debugging-symbols

Here's the steps to repro. Just installed IDA (free) v.7.0 on a brand-new installation of Windows 10 (x64) in a VM:

[image]

Then loaded a test PE file and started debugging it (using `Local Windows Debugger`):

[image]

So now I want to load symbols from the Microsoft server, say for `ntdll.dll` (or any other Windows module for that matter):

[image]

This fails with the following message in the output window:

[image]

```
DWARF: Cannot determine location of DWARF info for "C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll".
Could not load debug info for module: "C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll"
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: IDA > File > Load file > PDB file...

Comment: @Biswapriyo oh, I see. Thank you. I also noticed that in the menu for that command, it says, `"... you can specify .dll or .exe. In that case IDA will try to find and load PDB specified in its debug directory."` How do I configure that `debug directory`? I know in WinDbg one needs to provide a URL to Microsoft public symbols. Do I need to do the same for IDA?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by

1. Setting the environment variable
   `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*c:\pdb_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`
2. then tick the "auto load PDB files" in Debugger Options

Comment: That is really cool. I need to try it. One clarification: by setting an environment variable, do you mean in Windows?

Comment: @c00000fd yes, this is a Windows environment variable. It also affects WinDbg, Visual Studio and other tools that make _some_ use of the debug helper API to fetch symbols. You can fine-tune what location to use as cache and thereby keep your own local network share for your local symbols (e.g. of own products) but also consult the Microsoft servers and cache those symbols. If you have a VS subscription there's a chance you can also still access symbol packages for older Windows versions, if needed. But the symbol servers are reasonably fast, I find.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I still can't make it work. Is there https btw?

Comment: Don't think there are HTTPS URLs for the symbols, no. What exactly is it you can't make work?

Answer (score 1):

you must load pdb file when you pause this application, it must be paused state.

Comment: This looks like the start of a good answer but I feel it lacks some details and assumes a bit of knowledge that would better be explicit in the answer