# __security_cookie for function pointers in Windows 10

Tags: ida, windows, security

I'm curious about this `__security_cookie` that I keep seeing all over the `msvcp140.dll` from my Windows 10 x64 (insider build.)

Here's an example:

[image]

Note that the address for indirect function call (or `qword_18009FBD0`) is taken somewhere from the `.data` section:

[image]

Then it is XOR'ed with the `__security_cookie`:

[image]

I thought that `__security_cookie` is something that is used on the stack to guard against buffer-overflows. So they must be using some new security technique. Any idea what that is?

And a follow up question. I'm trying to statically analyze this binary code with IDA and this `__security_cookie` makes it very difficult to see what function is actually being called. For instance, here's how `qword_18009FBD0` looks like:

[image]

Any idea how to make those function addresses more legible?

Comment: Probably similar with [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16241/what-could-be-the-purpose-of-xoring-esp-with-a-global-variable-stack-canary-pr).

Comment: @Biswapriyo no, it's not the "GS cookie", even though it uses the same global variable name. Look at it, it has nothing to do with stack canaries, or "buffer overflows".

Answer (score 3):

Look for the writes to the `qword_18009FBD0` to see where it's initialized.

Apparently it's a part of an array called   `__encodedKERNEL32Functions` where various pointers to kernel32 functions are stored after being XORed with `__security_cookie`. You can rename the pointer to the kernel32 function's name to better see what is happening:

```
  ;(from initialize_pointers)
  lea     rdx, aClosethreadpoo ; "CloseThreadpoolTimer"
  mov     rcx, rbx        ; hModule
  mov     cs:qword_180092498, rax
  call    cs:__imp_GetProcAddress
  xor     rax, cs:__security_cookie
  lea     rdx, aCreatethreadpo_0 ; "CreateThreadpoolWait"
  mov     rcx, rbx        ; hModule
  mov     cs:pCloseThreadpoolTimer_xored, rax ;<- variable renamed

__crtCloseThreadpoolTimer proc near 
                sub     rsp, 28h
                mov     rax, cs:pCloseThreadpoolTimer_xored
                xor     rax, cs:__security_cookie
                jz      short loc_180036A8A
                call    cs:__guard_dispatch_icall_fptr ; calls CloseThreadpoolTimer()
loc_180036A8A:  
                add     rsp, 28h
                retn
__crtCloseThreadpoolTimer endp
```

This mitigation is not actually new and was already used in [VS2013 CRT](https://github.com/adityaramesh/concurrency_runtime/blob/master/VS2013_SP2/crt/src/winapisupp.c) although in a slightly different form. It is probably aimed at reducing the number of available API pointers in standard CRT DLLs to make exploitation harder.

Although `__security_cookie` is most commonly used for protecting data on the stack (GS and EH cookies), nothing prevents programmers from using it for other purposes as a simple source of entropy.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. There's a large function that repeatedly calls `GetProcAddress` on various system functions and populates that array. Unfortunately [I can't load symbols to see its name](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/22181/14864). By the way, do you know the name of this security mitigation that they are using there? I haven't seen this before, although it uses the name of the stack canary cookie.